# Yii2. Built-in client-side allowed HTML-tags validator?

Tags: yii2

When a user submits a certain form, I remove all of the forbidden HTML-tags from one of its fields before the whole form is validated, so here is a problem: when a user sends nothing, but forbidden HTML-tags in the field, the field will be totally empty, thus, my site will think it is originally so, and it warn the user that it shouldn't be empty.

To prevent that, I have to check the field's contents before submitting it on the client side to ensure that it has no forbidden HTML-tags and I wonder if there is such a feature built-in in Yii2? If not, is there a JavaScript interface to show any sort of warnings for the field the same way Yii2's validation shows them when something is wrong about the form's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check JavaScript validation at: https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/#working-with-activeform-via-javascript